# PHP: return an array from a class constructor

Tags: php, arrays, class, types, return

I just want to ask if it is possible to construct a class in PHP that returns an array when `print_r`ed

For example:

```
    <?php
    $c = new class(1,2,3){
        function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3){
            $this->value = [$var1 => [$var2, $var3]];
        }
    };

    print_r((array) $c);
```

i want it to result in:

> Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) )

instead i get

> Array ( [value] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) ) )

Comment: [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a function used for debug. It shouldn't matter how its output looks like. Why is it that important to you? I suspect you are trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: I am actually trying to get an array of a class that must be the exact style like mentioned above and simply used `print_r` to explain the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following code instead:

```
$c = new class(1,2,3){
    function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3){
        $this->$var1 = [$var2, $var3];
    }
};

print_r((array) $c);
```

This will provide the expected output.

Output:

> Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) )

Or you can try this:

```
$c = new class(1,2,3){
    function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3){
        $this->value = [$var1 => [$var2, $var3]];
    }
};

print_r((array) $c->value);
```

This will provide the same output:

> Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) )

Comment: Interesting approach to use `$this->${variable name}` as value. Is there a documentation to `$this->${variable name}` somewhere?

Comment: @thebigsmileXD Yes, these are called [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

This also works, but i consider @mega6382's answer as better

```
<?php
$c = new class(1,2,3) extends ArrayObject{
    function __construct(int $var1, int $var2, int $var3){
        parent::__construct([$var1 => [$var2, $var3]]);
    }
};

print_r((array) $c);
```

Gives:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) )
```